# Surface gaps in 3D print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, 3d-models

[image][image]

- The print needs to be 1 layer thick as it is a plane part. Even with supports, layer gaps like in image appear. It would be nice to have supports for it but the software is treating the object as if it was hollow therefore meaning infill makes no difference.
- Is there a way to "support" inside of the model walls? (not infill)
  -STL included now

Comment: Do you mean that you only want one wall/perimeter? (Instead of one layer) also, can you add a link to the STL file so we can slice it? Note that if the gradient of the part is too steep, you never get away with a single perimeter.